# Java component for showing web pages on embedded devices

Tags: java, webview, javafx, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I am working on a project on Raspberry PI on Java. We need to show some web pages on the application, so we need a web browser component.

We tried to get `WebView` from `JavaFX`, but its not available for embedded devices. Therefore, we tried to build `JavaFX` with `WebView`, but it throws a lot of errors on the build. The final error was that it was missing the package `libxml2-dev`.

The second attempt was on the DJ native swing, which has a web browser component. So we used it and installed all sorts of dependencies but it throws a `SWTException` saying no more handles and no `MOZILLA_FIVE_PATH` variable exist.

Is there a way to show web pages on the Raspberry PI?

Answer (score 1):

The support for JavaFX on embedded has been withdrawn by Oracle starting JDK for ARM 8u33. You can find the following statement in its [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk-8u33-arm-relnotes-2406696.html) :

> Starting with JDK 8u33, JavaFX Embedded is removed from the ARM bundle and is not supported.

If you need JavaFX on embedded devices (including Raspberry PI), you can try using the JavaFX Embedded SDK provided by Gluon. They have recently added [support for WebView on ARM](http://gluonhq.com/javafx-embedded-now-supports-webview/).

This can be easily installed using the necessary [plugin for one of the IDEs](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/trynow/) they support and adding the required configuration described in the [documentation](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_embedded_3).